# Django: How to customize an runserver_socketio command for manage.py

Tags: django, socket.io, gevent-socketio, django-socketio

I'm writing a realtime chatroom similar to [this package](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) with Django. It runs a separate WebSocket server with command

```
python manage.py runserver_socketio
```

But I can't figure out how to make the `runserver_socketio` command load my handler. The only related code I can find in the package [is here](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio/blob/master/django_socketio/management/commands/runserver_socketio.py) in `django-socketio/django_socketio/management/commands/runserver_socketio.py`:

```
server = SocketIOServer(bind, handler, resource="socket.io")
....
handler = WSGIHandler()
```

But why on earth is this `handler` related to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. the `manage.py runserver_socketio` command starts almost an identical server as `manage.py runserver` does. The only difference is that this new server can handle websocket protocol.

To see this ,suppose `runserver` runs on `127.0.0.1:8000` and `runserver_socketio` on `127.0.0.1:9000`. Just visit `127.0.0.1:9000` and you will get the same webpage with `127.0.0.1:8000`.

The secret lies in `django-socketio/django_socketio/example_project/urls.py`, which referencing `django-socketio/django_socketio/urls.py`. In this second `urls.py`, we can see that it loads `events.py` in our project.